# __construct() method in PHP Laravel not having enough arguments

Tags: php, laravel-5

Im trying to make a dynamic replication of Gistlog just as a benchmark for my programming skills, and I keep coming across a problem when testing the app. I enter the gist into the input bar as the app is running, but when I go to the next page, this error comes up saying that there are too few arguments for one of the methods: __construct(). It also states that 0 arguments are used when 1 is expected. I am using the method in the program, as can be seen in this file:

```
<?php

namespace Gistlog\Gists;

use Github\Client as Client;
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: JHaro
 * Date: 3/4/2017
 * Time: 8:14 AM
 */
 class GistRepository
 {
     private $github;

     public function __construct(Github\Client $github)
     {
         $this->github = $github;
     }

     /*
      * @param $url
      * return $gist
      */
      public function getByUrl($url)
      {
          $id = $this->extractedIdFromUrl($url);
          $gist = $this->getById($id);

          return Gist::fromGithub($gist);
      }

      public function extractedIdFromUrl($url)
      {
          $segments = explode('/', $url);

          return last($segments);
      }

      /**
      * @param $id
      */
      public function getById($id)
      {
          $gist = $this->github->gists()->show($id);
          dd($gist);
      }
  }
```

How can I fix this program to get by this error?

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: Try taking the constructor out, it isn't always required. Constructors are used to define variables when creating an object. Since it's expecting parameters and you're leaving it blank it's throwing errors.

Comment: I tried, but the program then states that the other variables cannot be detected.

Comment: I just edited the code displayed. Apparently I forgot to add a line that uses the github private variable. This should be reanalyzed so that we have the ability to solve the question.